# Using patsubst in Makefile to add paths to items

Tags: c, makefile

In my Makefile im doing like:

```
BINS = 1 2 3 4
```

then

```
OBJS := $(patsubst %,%.o,$(BINS))
```

This prints: `1.o 2.o 3.o 4.o`

But I want it to look like:

```
1/1.o 2/2.o 3/3.o 4/4.o
```

When I do it like this:

```
OBJS := $(patsubst %,%/%.o,$(BINS))
```

I get:

```
1/%.o 2/%.o 3/%.o 4/%.o
```

How can I accomplish what I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make isn't very good with dummy variables, but you can use [the `foreach` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Foreach-Function):

```
BINS = 1 2 3 4
OBJS := $(foreach bin,$(BINS),$(bin)/$(bin).o)
```